# How does 小 get the Sino-Vietnamse as "tiểu"?

Tags: pronunciation, chinese, vietnamese

I'm trying to re-construct the Sino-Vietnamese word of 小 (tiểu) from fanqie method mentioned [here](http://e-cadao.com/Chunom/quitachinhthanhamhanviet.htm). 
 At first, I looked up fanqie of the word from [this dictionary](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E5%B0%8F). 
小 has fanqie 私兆 which is "tư triệu" in Sino-Vietnamese. 
According to the rule in the website, "tư triệu" should be fanqied to "tiếu" in Sino-Vietnamese. However, the correct one is "tiểu". 
Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of 濁上歸去 (Mandarin pinyin: *zhuó shǎng guī qù*, Cantonese jyutping: *zuk6 soeng5 gwai1 heoi3*), also known as [濁上變去](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%BF%81%E4%B8%8A%E8%AE%8A%E5%8E%BB), and a very well-known issue in Chinese historical phonology.

This had already started in the late Tang: [in the](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E5%88%8A%E8%AA%A4) [《切韻刊誤》 *Mistakes of the Qièyùn*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cLgqAAAAYAAJ), writer 李涪 Lǐ Fú complains that 「上聲為去，去聲為上」 (the *shǎng* tone becomes *qù* and the *qù* tone becomes *shǎng*) in the accent of Wu. Interestingly, some of the examples used (辯、舅、皓) start with *voiced obstruents* (in historical rime dictionaries, 全濁), showing the tendency there.

The issue in this particular example is with the tone of 兆; as it started with a voiced obstruent in Middle Chinese, it underwent 濁上歸去. If we compare it with a range of modern (tonal!) varieties:

**兆**

> Middle Chinese (Zhengzhang): /**ɖˠ**iᴇu<sup>X</sup>/ (X implies 上聲)
>
> Middle Chinese (Pulleyblank): /**ɖ**iaw<sup>X</sup>/
>
> Standard Mandarin pinyin: **zhào** (fourth tone / grave accent implies 去聲)
>
> Cantonese Jyutping: **siu6** (sixth tone implies 去聲)
>
> Xiamen / Taiwanese Hokkien pe̍h-ōe-jī: **tiāu** (seventh tone / macron implies 去聲 and literary reading)
>
> Fuzhounese bàng-uâ-cê: **diêu** (sixth tone / circumflex implies 去聲 and literary reading)
>
> Sino-Vietnamese: **triệu** (*nặng* tone implies 去聲)

It seems that this particular lexeme underwent 濁上歸去 very thoroughly across the varieties. But some varieties did not:

> Wenzhounese ([IPA](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/ccr)): /dʑiɛ³⁴/  (tone numbers 34 imply 陽上聲)
>
> Taishanese ([IPA](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/ccr)): /siau²¹/ (tone numbers 21 imply 陽上聲)

Hence, it can be seen that there has been a change in 兆 (and other related characters) from 上聲 to 去聲, which makes using fanqie 反切 a little bit more difficult. One must "undo the effect" of 濁上歸去. Hence, you have to look up the *thượng* (上) column even though 兆 has *nặng* tone and is thus in the *khứ* (去) column. (Then you might have to re-do 濁上歸去 if it applies to the character!).

Other characters didn't have such a complete merger: 被 for example retains 上 in Cantonese when it refers to "bedding / quilt".

Comment: Thank you. I think I didn't really explain the question well. I'm more curious on how "tiểu" in Sino Vietnamese is formed from fanqie of 小.

Comment: The fanqie rule doesn't work in this case, because 兆 follows 濁上歸去.

Comment: Could you explain more about that?

Comment: @anhnha Have added something on the relevance of 濁上歸去 to practical use of 反切